# Looping into nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I am going through an exercise that asks me to remove the arrays that have elements that match with another variable.

e.g.

`filteredArray([[10, 8, 3], [14, 6, 23], [3, 18, 6]], 18)`

should return `[[10, 8, 3], [14, 6, 23]]`

Given the fact that we are working with nested arrays I though about using a double for to loop into each element.

Like this:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] != elem) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    // change code above this line
    return newArr;
  }
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

The expected result was to have an empty array, but it gives me:
`[3, 2, 3]`

The right solution is as follow:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].indexOf(elem) == -1) { //Checks every parameter for the element and if is NOT there continues the code
      newArr.push(arr[i]); //Inserts the element of the array in the new filtered array
    };
  };
  return newArr;
};

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Which makes sense, but I do not understand why mine is wrong.

Comment: Your `arr[i][j] != elem`,  well 2 != 3, so it will pass..   Also you have your `{` & `}` mixed up in yours too, so it's always going to return on the first loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with:

```
if (arr[i][j] != elem) {
  newArr.push(arr[i]);
}
```

You're pushing your array into `newArr` each time an inner element (`newArr[i][j]`) doesn't equal the filter element (`elem`). Instead, you want to push it into `newArr` if all the items in `arr[i]` are not equal to the `elem`. You could do this a few ways, one way would be to use a variable `found` which acts as a flag indicating whether the `elem` was found in any of the inner lists, and then add it if it was not found:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let found = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] == elem) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    
    if(!found) {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  
  // move return out of for loop
  return newArr;  // change code above this line
  
}
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26],
[19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `[3, 2, 3]` because you are returning from **inside** the first `for` loop. So, it only ever checks the first inner array. Even if you move it outside, the entire 2d array will be returned because every inner array has an element which will fail `arr[i][j] == elem` condition.

Alternatively, you could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this:

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  return arr.filter(a => !a.includes(elem))
}
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You check every element of the subarray, and if that does not match `elem` you push the subarray to the result. That means for `[3, 18, 6]` in your first example, it will check `3` against `elem` (`18`), then push that array, check `18` against `elem`, which won't fullfill the condition, then it will check `6` against `18` which does match again, the array gets pushed *again*. Instead you should check the whole array against the value, then push.

```
 outer: for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    if (arr[i][j] == elem) {
      continue outer; // if one matches, exit the inner loop
    }
    // all checked, push
    newArr.push(arr[i]);       
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There some wrong things in your code:

- You let return in for loop.
- You check every element in every sub array and push to result array when having the difference

I edit your code as below:

```
    function filteredArray(arr, elem) {   
let newArr = [];   
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  var check = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] == elem) {
       check = true;
      }
    }
       } // change code above this line
    return newArr; 
}
```